# Rails Routes - Shorter Non Resourcefull Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to setup some rails routes directed to the same controller, lets say "mycontroller" has 3 actions, and is not backed by a resource. Those 3 actions are GET, let's call them "action1", "action2" and "action3", so i end up setting something like

```
get "mycontroller/action1" => "mycontroller#action1", as: :action1_mycontroller
```

Once for every action. Is there a way of doing something like

```
resourceless :mycontroller do
  get 'action1'
  get 'action2'
  get 'action3'
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems it can be done just by using "namespace" `namespace :mycontroller do get "action1" end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like:

```
resources :my_controller, :only => [] do 
  collection do 
    get 'action1'
    get 'action2'
    get 'action3'
  end
end
```

Then in `rake routes`, you'll see:

```
 action1_my_controller_index GET    /my_controller/action1(.:format)  my_controller#action1
 action2_my_controller_index GET    /my_controller/action2(.:format)  my_controller#action2
 action3_my_controller_index GET    /my_controller/action3(.:format)  my_controller#action3
```

You can fiddle with `as:` to get your path names as you like them, I suspect.

Or, if you do (as you say):

```
namespace :mycontroller do 
  get "action1" 
  get "action2" 
  get "action3" 
end
```

You get:

```
    mycontroller_action1 GET    /mycontroller/action1(.:format)    mycontroller#action1
    mycontroller_action2 GET    /mycontroller/action2(.:format)    mycontroller#action2
    mycontroller_action3 GET    /mycontroller/action3(.:format)    mycontroller#action3
```

The latter (yours) being the better.

Comment: I was trying to avoid "reources" since i have no model to back this up. But thanks anyway! ;)

Comment: I understand. That's why I did `:only => []` which (1) generated no resourceful routes, but (2) allowed the `collection` syntax.

Comment: Your version has the benefit of prefixing the action name, it feels more natural. thank you!